# Gnome shell key mouse combo mapping change

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, window, window-manager, remapping

In gnome shell by default, keyboard and mouse combo mapping is :
Alt + left button = move window
Alt + middle button = resize window
Alt + right button = windows menu

My preferred meta key is Alt. (I can switch it to Super but it is not the purpose of this question.)

I'd like to swap the combo mapping to : 
Alt + left button = no action
Alt + middle button = resize window
Alt + right button = move window

I see a key "resize-with-right-button" in "org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences" schema and setting it to "true" value only swaps the middle and right mouse button. Thus it's no help. I see no other key to switch mouse button than that.

I'm on Version Gnome 3.32.2

Can anyone help please?
Thank you